# Is it possible to connect from my home ipv4 to my ipv6 company VPN

Tags: vpn, ipv6, ipv4

I need to know if it's possible to connect from my home IPv4 network to my company IPv6 network through VPN.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to connect?

Comment: In fact, i'm not a network professional. We hired one and I want to be sure that this is possible before talking to him.

Comment: It could be theoretically possible but it will depend on the VPN and maybe the OS. So too many unknowns here.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the configuration policy of the VPN provider.

> IP addresses make internetwork connections possible. They are like telephone numbers: both the sender and receiver must have an assigned number to connect. But with VPNs, there are actually two sets of addresses: the first set connects client and server on the public network. Once that connection is made,
>   the second set connects client and server through the VPN tunnel.

For example:

> You can configure both IPv4 and IPv6 address pools for the same group policy. If both versions of IP addresses are configured in the same group policy, clients configured for IPv4 will get an IPv4 address, clients configured for IPv6 will get an IPv6 address, and clients configured for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses will get both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.

**References**

- [Cisco ASA Series VPN CLI Configuration Guide: Configuring IP Addresses for VPNs (pdf)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/vpn/asa_91_vpn_config/vpn_addresses.pdf)
- [Dual-router setup w/ a dedicated VPN Router: A step-by-step tutorial](https://www.vpnuniversity.com/routers/setup-two-routers-with-dedicated-vpn-router)
- [How to Tunnel IPv6 over IPv4 (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ4wcVR5LM0)
- [Linux Hacks: HOWTO: ipv6-ipv6 tunnel and ip4-ipv6 tunnel in linux](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2008/02/howto-ipv6-ipv6-tunnel-and-ip4-ipv6.html)
- [vpn - Configure tunnel between IPv6 enabled server and local IPv4 network - Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35168/configure-tunnel-between-ipv6-enabled-server-and-local-ipv4-network)
- [networking - Forward IPv6 from WAN to Server with IPv4 - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/849296/forward-ipv6-from-wan-to-server-with-ipv4)
- [VPN Tests and Checks - The Ultimate How-To Guide | Restore Privacy](https://restoreprivacy.com/vpn-test/)